# Not able re-login after session timeout in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

the code in global.asax is

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       Session["init"] = 0;           
     }

     protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Session.Clear();             
     }
```

and in web.config file is

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
```

and after session time out login page is displayed.
User enters the field and clicks the login button.
on login button an ajax post is called as

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'Main/BoolLogin',
          data: { username: $("#userName").val(), pwd: $("#password").val() }
   });
```

Initially this call is working fine at the application start up
but after session timeout on clicking the login button

This error is displayed

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I am new to sessions.
Please Help.

Comment: Make sure your url is right in your `.ajax` call. At the moment it is relative to the current URL, so if you are on a page called `/User/Logout`, this will request the URL `/User/Main/BoolLogin`. Also, doesn't `Session_End` imply the Session is already cleared?

Comment: Thanks.That was helpful.i am new to sessions. can you send me link or something where i can read more about session management in asp.net. i searched but didnt get enough material to learn about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of relative URLs. Your URL starts without slash, that means it would be resolved relatively to current.

```
url: 'Main/BoolLogin',
```

When user is logged out your URL probably changes to something like that: http://domain.com/Auth/Login. So you get http://domain.com/Auth/Login/Main/BoolLogin instead of http://domain.com/Main/BoolLogin.

Start your URL with slash or better use [@Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper.

Comment: Thanks.That was helpful.i am new to sessions. can you send me link or something where i can read more about session management in asp.net. i searched but didnt get enough material to learn about.